# How can I index the current user in Quickblox?

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

I would like to get the current user id and login credential but I did not found a direct way so far.

How can I access the current user data ?

Comment: It may be helpful to you: `[QBSession currentSession].currentUser`

Comment: It's swift version: `QBSession.currentSession().currentUser`